# Fields missing in CSV file when writing with - UTL_FILE.put_line

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, runtime

We are facing an issue while generating some reports from oracle database from a PL/SQL procedure.
The issue is some of the fields in the generated CSV files are coming as blank.

We are using select statement to fetch the rows from the table based on the filter criteria.
Columns from each row from the result is then appended to a variable. 
v_invx_data_recordx           VARCHAR2 (15000)    := '';

The collected v_invx_data_recordx are later looped and written to file with below - 
`UTL_FILE.put_line (file_id, v_string_content);`

There are no exception thrown from the code, the CSV file is getting generated but having some fields missing in between. We ran the query separately and could see all fields are available in the selection query. Any inputs on how these fields can be missing during run time ? Will space issue in oracle cause such behavior?

Below is the relevant code snippet

````
v_inv_xdata_recordx := v_invx_data_recordx
              || '"' || tab_invx_data_tabx (i).bdx_airport_codex
              || '"' || con_comma;
         v_inv_xdata_recordx := v_invx_data_recordx
              || '"' || tab_invx_data_tabx (i).offx_airport_codex
              || '"' || con_comma;

p_tab_invx (i_line_count).file_contentx := v_invx_data_record;x

n_recx_countx := p_tab_invx.COUNT;

FOR i IN 1 .. n_recx_countx
  LOOP
     v_string_contentx := p_tab_inv (i).file_contentx;
     UTL_FILE.put_line (file_id, v_string_contentx);
  END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.put_line (file_id, v_string_contentx);```
````

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code to help us in helping you.

Comment: updated the details